# how to add icon at right side of RaisedButton?

Tags: flutter

How to add icon to RaisedButton at the right side

```
Padding(
       padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
          child: new SizedBox(
             width: double.infinity,
             child: new RaisedButton(
             textColor: Colors.white,
             color: coloraccent,
             onPressed: () {},
             child: const Text('UPADATE'),
        )),
       ),
```

Comment: do you want icon in RaisedButton or beside RaisedButton ?

Answer (score 17):

You can just wrap your `RaisedButton.icon` to the `Directionality` widget:

```
                    Directionality(
                      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                      child: RaisedButton.icon(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        color: Colors.deepPurple,
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_drop_down,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        label: Text(
                          "Category",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
```

Comment: This should be the approved answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this out, it works fine for me.

```
  child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () => navigateToLogin(context),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text("Continue",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                        Icon(Icons.navigate_next)                          
                      ],
                    ),
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why the downvote, instead of just downvoting and moving on

Answer (score 3):

use RaisedButton.icon constructor

```
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
        child: SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: RaisedButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(Icons.translate),
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Colors.lightBlue,
              label: const Text('UPADATE'),
              onPressed: () {},
            )),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2):

give a child to raised button like that

```
Row(
   mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween
   children: <Widget>[
     Text('some text'),
     Icon(Icons.home),
   ],

 ),
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use [RaisedButton.Icon](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton/RaisedButton.icon.html) but it was not enough for me, because I usually customize the buttons with many design styles, so I used some techniques for placing text and Icon with RaisedButton.

You can try this, It worked for me. Let me explain in the code.

```dart
// Create a Raised Button.
RaisedButton(
    color: Colors.pinkAccent, // Color pinkAccent
    child: Row( // Add a Row Widget for placing objects.
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, // Center the Widgets.
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, // Use all of width in RaisedButton.
    children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0), // Give to the text some space.
          child: Text(
              "Enviar",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18, // 18pt in font.
                color: Colors.white, // You can ommit it if you use textColor in RaisedButton.
              ),
          ),
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.send, // Send Icon. (Papper Plane Icon)
          color: Colors.white, // White Color. You can ommit it too if you use textColor property on RaisedButton.
          size: 18, // 18 pt, same as text.
        ),
    ],
    ),
    onPressed: () {}, /// For enabling the button
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [RaisedButton.icon](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton/RaisedButton.icon.html):

> Doc says:  Create a filled button from a pair of widgets that serve as
>   the button's icon and label.
>
> The icon and label are arranged in a row and padded by 12 logical
>   pixels at the start, and 16 at the end, with an 8 pixel gap in
>   between.

```
RaisedButton.icon(
    icon: Icon(Icons. ...), // <-- Icon you want.
    textColor: Colors.white,
    color: Colors.lightBlue,
    label: const Text('UPADATE'), // <-- Your text.
    onPressed: () {},
)),
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code. you can add your required width as per text length

```
 Container(
      height: 35.0,
      width: 95,
      child: RaisedButton(
        elevation: 10,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(15.0),
          ),
        ),
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Call', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
            SizedBox(width: 10),
            Icon(Icons.call),
          ],
        ),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you still resist using `RaisedButton.Icon` instead of using the normal `RaisedButton` with `Row`  widget as a child

Then you can swap between `label` and `icon` attributes because they both take a widget.

Like this:

```
RaisedButton.icon(
    icon: const Text('UPADATE'),
    label: Icon(Icons.translate),
    textColor: Colors.white,
    color: Colors.lightBlue,
    onPressed: () {},
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my two buttons, Back and Next

```
Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          RaisedButton(
            color: const Color(0xFFFFB822), // Color pinkAccent
            child: Row(
              // Add a Row Widget for placing objects.
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, // Center the Widgets.
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, // Use all of width in RaisedButton.
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 10, width: 10),
                Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back_ios, // Send Icon. (Papper Plane Icon)
                  color: Colors.black, // White Color. You can ommit it too if you use textColor property on RaisedButton.
                  size: 18, // 18 pt, same as text.
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0), // Give to the text some space.
                  child: Text(
                    "Back",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                      color: Colors.black, // You can ommit it if you use textColor in RaisedButton.
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            onPressed: () {},

            /// For enabling the button
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            color: const Color(0xFFFFB822), // Color pinkAccent
            child: Row(
              // Add a Row Widget for placing objects.
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, // Center the Widgets.
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, // Use all of width in RaisedButton.
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0), // Give to the text some space.
                  child: Text(
                    "Next",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                      color: Colors.black, // You can ommit it if you use textColor in RaisedButton.
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_forward_ios, // Send Icon. (Papper Plane Icon)
                  color: Colors.black, // White Color. You can ommit it too if you use textColor property on RaisedButton.
                  size: 18, // 18 pt, same as text.
                ),
              ],
            ),
            onPressed: () {},

            /// For enabling the button
          ),
        ],
      ),
```